# Sequences generated from commuted quaternions and general commuted linear transformations

Tags: gr.group-theory, ds.dynamical-systems, noncommutative-algebra, quaternions, cycles

Given a pair of non-commuting linear transformations, $A$ and $B$, define the "next
pair" in a sequence as $A*B$ and $B*A$.  I am interested in finite cycles (i.e.,
the sequence eventually returns to the original $A$ and $B$).  Is this studied
somewhere?  What is known about the maximum order of such cycles?  (By the way, it
is easy to see that my original "non-commuting" requirement can be relaxed to
"non-equal" because I am dealing with a cycle.)

In particular, I've actually been looking at quaternions and one example cycle
(with order 8) can be generated from:
$$A=\space\space\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}-\frac{j}{2\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}} + \frac{k}{2\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}}}$$
$$B=\space\space\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+\frac{j}{2\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}} + \frac{k}{2\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}}}$$
I can find longer cycles, but only numerically.  So, in the space of just quaternions, what is the largest cycle order possible?
Is it infinite?

**EDIT (Aug 10 2021):**
Without loss of generality for the quaternion problem, I believe this is just a matter of finding finite cycles which can be generated from two degrees of freedom (real $\alpha$ and $\beta$):
$$A=\space\space\sqrt{1-\alpha^2-\beta^2}-\alpha{j} + \beta{k}$$
$$B=\space\space\sqrt{1-\alpha^2-\beta^2}+\alpha{j} + \beta{k}$$
Seems easy, doesn't it?

Comment: It seems that you're looking for relations of the form $A=w(A,B)$ or $B=w(A,B)$  where $w$ is a positive word. This is rather a (semi)group theory problem; I've added the group theory and dynamics tags.

Comment: First, I'm unclear what you mean by a cycle. Are you asking whether the sequence contains a single term twice, or are you asking whether the entire sequence contains a finite number of terms? Secondly, Is the question whether there are arbitrarily long finite cycles? or whether there are $A$ and $B$ for which your sequence has no repeats?

Comment: @AnthonyQuas I am only interested in cycles where "the entire sequence contains a finite number of terms" and I want to know "whether there are arbitrarily long finite cycles".

Comment: Since the quaternion group contains a non-Abelian free group, it is easy to construct a pair A and B for which this sequence will not contain repetitions. It is sufficient to take such A and B that generate a free group.